# Bootstrap 4 - left sidebar with menu after click icon

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[example photo sidebar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTZ1V.png)

I  looking for solution for create sidebar like on above photo.

[photo2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avABI.png)

After click icon sidebar then display menu.

I have somelike this but I need to add extra menu after click like first screen:

https://www.codeply.com/p/yRugA2FB3I

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
      Dropdown link
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    </div>
  </li>
```

Put this as dropdown list, try to edit css of the dropdown item.

or use this as well:

```
   <!-- Default dropright button -->
<div class="btn-group dropright">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropright
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <!-- Dropdown menu links -->
  </div>
</div>
```

it is the element of bootstrap 4 that do dropdown on the right.